# What determines the surface texture width and height for camera?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera

Here's a snippet from my implementation of my custom camera page.

For some reason, I keep getting a lower resolution textureView/SurfaceTexture height and width than I expect. I want to keep the native maximum camera resolution (or picture size) my native camera on my phone takes normally. However, with the way I have it setup right now, the resolution of my textureView is lower than the native camera resolution. I'm wondering why? I tried to debug and seems OnSurfaceTextureAvailable() seems to be setting the width and height incorrectly. Where is it grabbing it from?

```
public class CameraPage : PageRenderer, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener 
{
    global::Android.Hardware.Camera camera;

    Activity activity;
    CameraFacing cameraType;
    TextureView textureView;
    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;

    public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable (SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
    {
        GetCameraInstance();

        if (camera != null) {
            textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            surfaceTexture = surface;

            camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);

            PrepareAndStartCamera();
        }
    }

    private void GetCameraInstance()
    {
        try {
            camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)CameraFacing.Back);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore any exception
        }
    }

    public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed (SurfaceTexture surface)
    {
        StopCameraPreviewAndRelease();
        return true;
    }

     private void StopCameraPreview()
    {
        try {
            if (camera != null)
                camera.StopPreview();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void StopCameraPreviewAndRelease()
    {
        try {
            if (camera != null) {
                StopCameraPreview();
                camera.SetPreviewCallback(null);
                camera.Release();
                camera = null;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged (SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
    {
        PrepareAndStartCamera ();
    }

    public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated (SurfaceTexture surface)
    {

    }

    private void PrepareAndStartCamera ()
    {
            var flashMode = GetFlashMode();
            SetCameraParameters(flashMode);

            StopCameraPreview();

            var display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
            if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0) {
                camera.SetDisplayOrientation (90);
            }

            if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270) {
                camera.SetDisplayOrientation (180);
            }

            if (flashOn)
                toggleFlashButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.flash_on);
            else
                toggleFlashButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.flash_off);

            camera.StartPreview ();
    }
}
```

This is how I'm setting my textureView:

```
textureView = view.FindViewById<TextureView> (Resource.Id.textureView);
textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
```

textureView in my cameraLayout:

```
<TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#99b4d1ff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />
```

That is, I'm expecting 2576x1932 resolution when the photo is taken and saved. But I am getting 1451x720 instead when the photo is taken and saved. Seems like that was determined to be the textureView size (but I want the native camera resolution size).

EDIT: Here's the way the photo is being taken of:

```
private async void TakePhotoButtonTapped (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{
        try
        {
            StopCameraPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            camera.Reconnect();
            PrepareAndStartCamera();
            StopCameraPreview();
        }

        var image = textureView.Bitmap;

        var imageQuality = AppState.ApplicationInfo.AndroidImageCompressionFactor;
        using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream ()) {
            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, imageQuality, imageStream);
            image.Recycle();
            imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray ();
        }
        count +=1;

        textView.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
        _images.Add(imageBytes);
        camera.StartPreview ();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see you calling setPictureSize to pick resolution you prefer. Texture size reflects the size of the TextureView element on your screen

Comment: oh so I need to call setPictureSize so that the pictureSize used is the correct one that the native camera uses and not set to the textureView size by default? Where should I call setPictureSize?

Comment: you can do that right after opening the camera, you can first get the SupportedPictureSizes from GetParameters to pick from known sizes

Comment: so I know how to get the picture size but when I get the size object... what do I do with it?

Comment: there is SetPreviewSize and SetPictureSize on parameters , then you can SetParameters back on camera

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I edited my post to show how I'm taking the photo. Is that wrong? I'm setting the image to the textureView and saving that image...

Comment: @OlegBogdanov how do I do that?

Comment: sorry my comment was wrong, removed

Comment: can you add your PrepareAndStartCamera ? I still cant see you setting any sizes

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I am not hardcoding any sizes is what I am saying. Somehow, natively SurfaceTextureAvailable renders the lower res size I mentioned above. Added prepare and start camera to the long code snippet.

Comment: I think its finds the best fit among supported resolution, the one that matches screen size the best